# An exercise problem in Axler Linear Algebra Done Right for linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations

So I have written down a proof but feel uncertain about whether it is valid or not, could somebody please Check it and, if there exists any gap, inform me?
  The question is the following (Chapter 3 problem 3) :

> Suppose that a vector space $V$ is finite dimensional. Prove that any linear map on a subspace of $V$ can be extended to a linear map on $V$. In other words, show that if $U \subseteq V$ and $S \in \mathcal L(U,W)$, where $\mathcal L(U,W)$ denotes the vector space of all linear transformations from $U$ into $W$, then there exists $T \in \mathcal L(V,W)$ such that $Tu=Su \ \ \forall u \in U$.

My proof is as follows:

If one basis of $U$ is $ \{u_1,...,u_k \} $, then we can extend this basis to a basis of $V$ which is $ \{u_1,...u_k,v_1,...v_n\}$.
$\forall u \in U$, $$ u = \sum_{i=1}^k a_iu_i$$

but also, we can write this as $$ u = \sum_{i=1}^k a_iu_i + \sum_{j=1}^n 0*v_j$$

Thus define $T:V \to W$ such that $Tu_i=Su_i$ so $$Tu = \sum_{i=1}^k a_iTu_i+\sum_{j=1}^n 0*Tv_j = \sum_{i=1}^k a_iTu_i = Su$$

Is there anything wrong with my proof? Please notify me any error and gap, and suggestions on the method of proof I use is welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're implicitly defining $Sv_j=0$. It's better to be explicit.

Your proof can be phrased in words as follows:

The key idea is that a linear transformation is determined by its values on a basis. Take a basis of $U$ and complete it to a basis of $V$. Define $S$ to coincide with $T$ on the basis of $U$ and as $0$ (or anything else really) on the rest of the basis. Then $S$ is a linear transformation on $V$ that extends $T$.

Comment: Yes I see what you are talking about. Thanks for pointing out the key idea.

Comment: I just revisited this question and found my solution to be false due to non-linearity

Answer (score 1):

In your proof, since $T: V \to W$, you also need to define the image of the $v_i$ in your extended basis. Otherwise, $T$ will not really know how to act on a vector in $V$ that is not in $U$.

You can do this by picking $n$ vectors from $W$ and setting $Tv_i=w_i$.

Your verification that for all $u \in U$ you have $Tu=Su$ looks good.